# How to set a value on a directive's scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have multiple AngularJS directives that are nearly identical - there are only two differences: the template URL and one single element in the linking function. Both are constant for each directive. So, for simplicity's sake, this is how it looks like:

```
app.directive("myDirective", [function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "this/path/changes.html",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var veryImportantString = "this_string_changes";
            // a few dozen lines of code identical to all directives
        }
    };
}]);
```

Now, moving the linking function to a commonly available place is obvious. What is not so obvious to me is how to set that "very important string" on the scope (or otherwise pass it to the directive) without declaring it in the HTML.

Here's what I've tried.

```
app.directive("myDirective", [function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "this/path/changes.html",
        scope: {
            veryImportantString: "this_string_changes"
        },
        link: someCommonFunction
    };
}]);
```

Nope, apparently the scope config doesn't take values from nobody. I can bind a value coming from the HTML attribute, but this is precisely what I don't want to do.

Also tried this:

```
app.directive("myDirective", [function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "this/path/changes.html",
        veryImportantString: "this_string_changes",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var veryImportantString = this.veryImportantString;
        }
    };
}]);
```

But alas, the linking function is then called with `this` set to something else.

I assume this might work:

```
app.directive("myDirective", [function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "this/path/changes.html",
        scope: true,
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            // no access to the scope...
            attrs.veryImportantString = "this_string_changes";
            return someCommonFunction;
        }
    };
}]);
```

However, I am not 100% sure this is what I want either, as it reeks of being a dirty workaround.

What are my other options?

Answer (score 2):

I have devised a completely different approach: using a factory-like function to spawn directives.

```
var factory = function(name, template, importantString) {
    app.directive(name, [function() {
        return {
            scope: true,
            templateUrl: template,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var veryImportantString = importantString;
                // directive logic...
            }
        };
    }]);
};
```

Then, in order to create individual directives, I simply call:

```
factory("myDirective", "/path/to/template.html", "important");
factory("myDirective2", "/path/to/template2.html", "important2");
```

Comment: I like this - very neat

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

Before wherever you define `someCommonFunction`, add the line

```
var veryImportantString = "someOptionalDefault"
```

This then puts `veryImportantString` in scope of both your `someCommonFunction` and `.directive()`

Then you can change your directive code to:

```
app.directive("myDirective", [function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "this/path/changes.html",
        scope: true,
        link: function(args){
          veryImportantString = "thatUberImportantValue";
          someCommonFunction(args);
        }
    };
}]);
```

[**Proof of concept fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLR52/)

Comment: While the idea is interesting, there is a slight problem, illustrated by this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GLR52/2/ - the injected dependencies are out of scope :(

Comment: My `someCommonFunction` suffered the same drawback, that's why I ended up using the directive factory :)